# How to loop within a for loop to get multiple values with the same ID

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I want to get some data from a MySql database which has the same ID but different values. [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvEF0.jpg) (this is just a sample)
Although the venue styles are different, I want to pull all the styles with the same ID. I'm using a foreach loop to get the data from the database.

How can I improve my code to achieve what I want.

`<?php 
     $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT vf_venues.title, vf_venues.mainimage, 
     vf_venues.permalink, vf_venuestyles.slug 
     FROM vf_venues 
     LEFT JOIN vf_venuestyles ON vf_venuestyles.vid=vf_venues.vid WHERE 
     vf_venuestyles.vid=vf_venues.vid" );?>`

```
<div class="venue-list venue-grid">
<?php

foreach ( $myrows as $myrow ) {
//pull the data from the DB
"<pre>"
$venueName = $myrow->title;
$mainImage = $myrow->mainimage;
$permalink = $myrow->permalink;
$slug = $myrow->slug;
$vid = $myrow->vid;
"<pre>"
?>

<li class="venue-block block">
    <div class="venue-img">
        <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $mainImage; ?>">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="venue-details"><h2><?php echo $venueName; ?></h2></div>
    <?php echo $slug; ?>
    <?php echo $vid; ?>
</li>

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull all the different styles of any *specific* id?

Comment: Get rid of your WHERE clause

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - yes exactly but trying to do this dynamically

Comment: @Strawberry - did, no difference. Its outputting all the venue styles in a list. for every different style. its outputting the same venue with the different styles. So if a venue had 6 venue styles, it would show the venue 6 times with each of the venue styles appended to it

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cf428/3

Comment: Thanks for the progress report.

Comment: @Strawberry - so if i had a venue style of 'christmas', 'ampersnad' and 'modern', it will show the venue 3 times for each of the styles. I just want all the styles associated with id to show on one venue. Does this make sense?

Comment: No. Hence the information provided in the accepted answer at the linked question. Note that an EDIT button is provided.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm new to stack overflow. I've added me database schema on the link you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by creating a for loop within the existing for loop. I then created a sql query to pull the venue styles for that venue.